# How to get code behind variable value into repeater

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable, repeater

I have a variable in my code behind file in asp.net say string myVariable = "SomeValue";

I use this declaration in the code-behind:

```
  Public myVariable As String = "SomeValue"
```

I want to bind this string inside the in Repeater.

```
 <td id="Td5" class="Text" style="text-align:right; width:70px;" >
        <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "'<%=myVariable%>'", "{0:N2}")%>
 </td>
```

The Repeater is binded using a datatable. I  use vb.net

thanks for yours comments.

Comment: You should be able to do just `<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, myVariable, "{0:N2}")%>`

Answer (score 0):

Set your value within session and then bind sessionh  with `<%=Session("yourfiledName")%>`